# fix for XSS vulnerabilites in javascript files reported by HP FOD tool

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that handles my dashboard.js files in my project on scanning over HP FOD tool, following vulnerability is identified on the line:

```
 var selectOption = $("#county option[value=" + selectValue + "]").text();
```

Tool says the following:

> The method lambda() in handlers.js sends unvalidated data to a web
>   browser on line above.

Comment: Well your sending unvalidated data to a web browser on line above, don't... I'm not sure what else to say. Not least of which you seem to of failed to ask an actual question

Comment: Where does `selectValue` come from? And what is this code supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't say where `selectValue` comes from (I think that's the important bit) and there's always a limit in what static analysis can accomplish.

In any case, the worst case scenario I can think of right now is getting a selector that matches arbitrary items on page and removes them:

```js
var selectValue = "''], *, foo[bar";
var selector = "#county option[value=" + selectValue + "]";
var selectOption = $(selector);
console.log("Final selector: %s", selector, selectOption.length);
console.log("Selected items: %s", selectOption.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What that means is the variable `selectValue` could contain anything and it's used to populate the value of an option that could be submitted to the server.

If you are sure that you sanitise your country options **on the server** you have addressed the issue.

Any HTML form element could be tampered with and should be sanitised on the server anyway.